# Move objects from AWS S3 to MediaStore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-mediastore

As a legacy from the previous version of our system, I have around 1 TB of old video files on AWS S3 bucket. Now we decided to migrate to AWS Media Services and all those files should be moved to MediaStore for the access unification.

**Q:** Is there any way to move the data programmatically from S3 to MediaStore directly?

After reading AWS API docs for these services, the best solution I've found is to run a custom Python script on an intermediate EC2 instance and pass the data through it.

Also, I have an assumption, based on pricing, data organization and some pieces in docs, that MediaStore built on top of S3. That's why I hope to find a more native way to move the data between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've clarified this with AWS support. There is no way to transfer files directly, although, it's a popular question and, probably, will be implemented.

Now I'm doing this with an intermediate EC2 server, a speed of internal AWS connections between this, S3 and MediaStore is quite good. So I would recommend this way, at least, for now.